# Nginx can't serve static content and return 403(Forbidden) error page

Tags: nginx

I am new to nginx and trying to serve static contents with nginx and getting 403 error.I have server config like this:

```
server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
    root /Users/ismayilmalik/Documents/github/nginx-express;

    location / {
        index index.html;
}
```

I have executed commands below:

```
chmod -R 755 /nginx-express
chmod -R 644 /nginx-express/*.*
```

And the folder has **drwxr-xr-x** rigt.What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your nginx error logs to get details.

Run this command to show last errors:

```
tail -20 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good to go through error logs located /var/log/nginx/***.error. I had problems similar to this once. The solution was the user nginx was running as.

If nginx is running as www then www will not have access to ismayilmalik folders unless you also grant access to /Users/ismayilmalik home folder, but that is not secure. The best solution would be to allow nginx to run as  ismayilmalik if you want to access your home folder through nginx.

Comment: I think so but the problem is I can't find logs in /var/log path.There are no nginx folder.

Comment: Look in the nginx.conf file located at /etc/nginx/nginx.conf if you see two lines with access_log [some path] and error_log [some path]. [some path] will tell you where the log files are stored.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it finally.Actually nginx had all permission to serve static content from:

```
/Users/ismayilmalik/Documents/github/nginx-express;
```

The reason was when started nginx could not create **error.log** file in it'sroot directory. After manually creating the file it worked fine. I am using macOs and to find logs folder executed the command below to find all enironment variables for nginx:

```
nginx -V
```

BTW before this I had changed nginx user to from **nobody** to admin in main config file like below.

```
user [username] [usergroup]
```

By default nginx master process runs under **root** and child process under **nobody**.